# installing VS2010 express on server

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2010, C#, ASP.NET & SQL Server 2008 are my main development tools, recently I've bought a VDS (virtual dedicated server) which runs on Win server 2008 R2, my vendor has install SQL server 2008 express on my server, but I'm going to have VS2010 on my server also, as I think running and debugging my web apps on server would be much faster and easier than remote tests, is it possible at all to use VS2010 and code in my server? I can use remote desktop to view my server so I think it should be possible.
I use VS2010 ultimate on my local machine, what is the difference between VS2010 express and ultimate as I've that VS express is free of charge, so it is easy to download and install it on server

what should I do now? guide me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use remote debugging.  Depending on how much control you have on your server you may be able to get it working.  In Visual Studio when you choose *Debug -> Attach To Process* it allows you to specify a remote machine to connect to.  On the remote machine you'd connect to the w3wp.exe process associated with your AppPool. If you went this route you would not need Visual Studio on your production machine.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the details of your situation but why would you want to debug your application on your (production) server? That is what your development environment (local machine) is for. Once you are satisfied with your local build you deploy it to your server.

Comment: yes but my database is on my server, also sometimes working on server instead of local machine has advantages, for instance you can instantly debug your code

Comment: @Ali_dotNet Sorry I am still not sure why you would want to do that, why would you not install SQL Server 2008 express in your development environment? You shouldn't really be debugging anything on your server, logging yes but not debugging. Apologies if I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I agree with martijn_himself. Use logs on production.  Copy your production databases locally as needed to debug (if you need production data to solve the problem). On a small website you could get away with debugging on production but I don't recommend getting in that habit.  When you set a break point on your production code and execution stops on the break point what do you think will happen to the other users on your website?  Everything will pause.  That is not good...